# Where to ask questions about a GIS API?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a programming question regarding a GIS API, but it is more on the programming side. Which site should it go to? GIS or Stack Overflow? It's about a JavaScript API and how layer objects are being built.

The question is going to be along the lines of:

> "Why does this firebug say that layer.fields is undefined when the
>   REST page shows that there are fields being returned from an ArcGIS
>   server?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try it on the more specialist [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) first. They already have 250+ questions tagged [`arcgis-javascript-api`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api), so you're more likely to get an answer there than on Stack Overflow (where we only have 36 questions tagged both [`arcgis` and `javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis+javascript)).  If they find your question to be too programming specific, they can always migrate it to SO.