# Where to ask questions about algorithms used in GIS or GPS-based apps?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to ask a few questions about algorithm to be used in GIS or GPS-based application, i.e.:

> Which accelerometer's axis and with value in which range, will tell me, if device is moving?
>
> How to probe GPS, to ensure best location and battery performance in the same time?
>
> An algorithm to determine (basing on device parameters), if device is outside building?

Where would be the best place to post them? Would that be:

- Programmers (a question about general algorithm, not specific to any programming language)?
- Stack Overflow (a question about [software algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97875/189165))?
- GIS (a question similar to questions about [GIS API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162016/189165))?
- *some other SE site*?
- *nowhere* (off-topic on every SE site)?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [gis.StackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) would be an appropriate one.

That's definitely a place for last two question; but the first one, as I think, more appropriate for [programmers.StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) due to it's clearly algorithmic idea (and this question can be applied not only for GIS systems, but also for games, software and many others).

Comment: +1 I think [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is well worth a shot too.  Any "questions about algorithm to be used in GIS or GPS-based application" would certainly be triaged as on-topic far more often than not.  GIS is core business there and GPS is not to far off centre too.

Answer (score 1):

In short, GPS questions are ontopic in many places.
(Which is fine).

I suggest the first two (at least),
belong on [electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Which as a [number of GPS questions.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps)

The first is basically about a hardware function on the GPS module, so EE.

The second is about battery life, and maximizing it on some kind of embedded system, another EE problem.

The third could go to alot of places, and it would not be off topic in any of them, similar questions already exist in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669930/determine-if-user-is-indoor-or-outdoor),  [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111906/how-can-i-detect-if-an-android-device-is-indoor-outdoor), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324240/distinguishing-between-indoor-and-outdoor-by-the-gps-provider), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879756/detecting-whether-gps-is-available-ipad-internal-cellular-or-external-bluetooth).
I haven't found any on the younger sites, But I am sure it would do fine on GIS, Robotics, EE, and probably a few platform specific ones such as Android, R-Pi, Arduino.

Comment: I think you're missing the point with suggestion, that these questions belongs to EE, as they have nothing to do with electronics. The device is there, standardized, with some API, giving me these or that parameters. And I need to know which of them and how often should I read or for what values to look for to achieve desired effect or calcualate, what I need to calculate. I'm unable and not willing to deal with anything in the hardware layer. This is purely programming / algorithmic or GIS-related question, that is much more close to math than do electronics.

Comment: But questions like  how often to Poll hardware devices, are based on the hardware properties of the device, and the battery,
It's an Electronics problem. Most devices are standardized in electronics. Plenty of questions on EE are about understanding standardised electronics hardware/making best us of it, rather than modifying it.

Comment: Agree. But reading any data from hardware is always software / API layer, not the hardware layer. If you're unsure, go there and ask at their meta, if questions about APIs that uses hardware are on-topic there. I'm pretty sure, they're not. Notice, that may question is about API / end-program, not even about firmware level (maybe questions about this would be on-topic on EE, but I'm uncertain either). I write my code using 100% API specification and I absolutely don't care about hardware, what is below that API.

Comment: so then you do not care about battery performance. My mistake. As I read your question, that was a major point. You may like to edit your question with this clarification.

Comment: I **do care**, but on API / code layer. Simple example: If I'll be probing GPS signal every second, while device is inside a building, I will probably kill the battery with 1-2 hours (each mobile device waste battery enormously, when can't "see" satellites). So, one of the question is about algorithm to determine, if device is inside a building to stop frequent probing in these situations. When we're talking about mobile devices, badly written code can kill battery quick, even if itself has nothing to do with the hardware. See my point?

Comment: Ah I think I get you. So you want to save batterylife vai something like a "backoff" algorithm, which backs off when it can't get a good fix. I see now. You are correct EE wouldn't be ideal for that. It could go many places. I suggest SO for biggest crossskilled audience.