# Tag's description diplayed in top-left corner

Tags: discussion, bug

While asking [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245759/189165) I've managed to display tag's description it site's top-left corner:

[image]

Is that a bug or I'm just badly lucky? :>

Comment: Try hard-reloading.

Comment: That was one-time catch, of course! :> It is not a permanent problem. I'm asking to check, if this is something devs should be notified about?